# "init "and "mail" fields in the users table

Tags: users, database

What is the difference between the "init" and "email" fields?

```
mail varchar(64)  User's e-mail address.
init varchar(64)  E-mail address used for initial account creation.
```

Comment: Btw, if anyone is getting here because update warnings were sent to `admin@example.com`: Even though the admin account might have `$user->init === 'admin@example.com'`, the actual place to look is admin/reports/updates/settings, which might also contain an `admin@example.com`. (This was on an old website, i have no idea how it got there :) )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference is that *mail* is the actual email address used by the user, while *init* contains, in a plain Drupal installation, the email address used when the user account was created.
In the case the [Bakery Single Sign-On System](http://drupal.org/project/bakery) module is installed in a slave site (in Bakery parlance), the *init* field contains the link to the user account on the master site.

So, the *init* field could be described as the field that unequivocally identifies a user account, and that is (by default, when third-party modules don't change its content) set to contain the initial e-mail address. (That seems the reason why the field has been named *init*.)

Drupal.org uses the *init* field in the case users lose the access to their account, and create a new account to report that. They are asked (not publicly) which email they used when registering their previous account; a Drupal.org administrator would then verify that is exactly the email they used while registering the lost account by reading the database content. (There isn't a module that allows to do so automatically, for what I know.)

Comment: Another difference worth mentioning, is that while the mail can change many times through the lifetime of the user profile on that site, the init will stay same. This can be used should the account be hacked and the e-mail and password changed.